# Mostrar registro de una consulta uno a la vez

Tags: sql

necesito hacer una funcion donde vaya leyendo uno por uno los registros de una consulta como : `select * from alumnos`
para poder ir usando los datos una a la vez,e ir modificandolos uno a la vez.

Por ende la idea era meterlo dentro de un while e ir modificandolos pero nose como ir seleccionando uno por uno y sin repetirlos.
Todo esto en lenguaje SQL 2008

Comment: Con que lenguaje pretendes modificar el los datos de la consultas.

Answer (score 0):

Esto sería un ejemplo de lo necesitas hacer, un cursor q recorra las tuplas y un bucle para iterar por ellas y hacer lo q necesitas

```
   SET NOCOUNT ON;  

    DECLARE @vendor_id int, @vendor_name nvarchar(50),  
        @message varchar(80), @product nvarchar(50);  

    PRINT '-------- Vendor Products Report --------';  

    DECLARE vendor_cursor CURSOR FOR    SELECT VendorID, Name   FROM Purchasing.Vendor   WHERE PreferredVendorStatus = 1   ORDER BY VendorID;  

    OPEN vendor_cursor  

    FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor    INTO @vendor_id, @vendor_name  

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   BEGIN  
        PRINT ' '  
        SELECT @message = '----- Products From Vendor: ' +   
            @vendor_name  

        PRINT @message  

        -- Declare an inner cursor based     
        -- on vendor_id from the outer cursor.  

        DECLARE product_cursor CURSOR FOR   
        SELECT v.Name  
        FROM Purchasing.ProductVendor pv, Production.Product v  
        WHERE pv.ProductID = v.ProductID AND  
        pv.VendorID = @vendor_id  -- Variable value from the outer cursor  

        OPEN product_cursor  
        FETCH NEXT FROM product_cursor INTO @product  

        IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0   
            PRINT '         <<None>>'       

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
        BEGIN  

            SELECT @message = '         ' + @product  
            PRINT @message  
            FETCH NEXT FROM product_cursor INTO @product  
            END  

        CLOSE product_cursor  
        DEALLOCATE product_cursor  
            -- Get the next vendor.  
        FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor   
        INTO @vendor_id, @vendor_name   END    CLOSE vendor_cursor;   DEALLOCATE vendor_cursor;
```

Answer (score -1):

Si es como lo estoy pensando, sería agrupando el select por la campos que contiene la tabla y de esa manera no se repiten los datos:

```
Select Codest,Nombre,Apellido from estudiantes
group by Codest,Nombre,Apellido
```

Y con la aplicación, del lenguaje que sea, obtienes esa información y con un ciclo (como te guste) en el datatable o dataset vas editando cada uno de los registros que tengas.